# Why didn't my user get assigned to the group I had added myself to?

Tags: gnome, groups

*I'm on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04. During installation, I chose the minimal installation instead of the standard one.*

I just added myself to the `docker` group using the following command

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker danny
```

I have logged out from my GNOME session (I tried both, from the top bar's menu, and from searching for "[logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx2ZQ.png)"). But my user did not get assigned to the `docker` group. However, if I `su` into my user, the group is there so the previous command did not fail.

```
$ groups
danny adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ groups danny
danny adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
$ su - danny
$ groups
danny adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

I had to do a full OS reboot for the change to take effect.

I have already rebooted, but this the ouput of `id`;

```
$ id
uid=1000(danny) gid=1000(danny) groups=1000(danny),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare),999(docker)
```

**But I'm wondering why logging out isn't enough?**

P.S. I am able to reproduce this behavior by adding myself to any random group, not just `docker`.

Comment: I even tried `su - $USER` too, same result. There are no other users on this installation (besides the system ones). Also, I am able to reproduce it with any group, not just docker.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `newgrp` command to join a new group:

```
jean@myLinux:~$ id
uid=1000(jean) gid=1000(jean) groups=1000(jean),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare),129(vboxusers)
jean@myLinux:~$ newgrp - newgroup
jean@myLinux:~$ id
uid=1000(jean) gid=1003(newgroup) groups=1003(newgroup),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare),129(vboxusers),1000(jean)
```

I must confess that I'm as surprised as you that logout / login doesn't assign the new group, but `su -` does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reboot to assign the additional group to your user. In the running shell the group assignment doesn't change, but it does in a new shell:

```
jean@myLinux:~$ sudo groupadd tester
[sudo] password for jean: 
jean@myLinux:~$ sudo usermod -a -G tester jean
jean@myLinux:~$ id
uid=1000(jean) gid=1000(jean) groups=1000(jean),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare),129(vboxusers)
jean@myLinux:~$ su - jean
Password: 
jean@myLinux:~$ id
uid=1000(jean) gid=1000(jean) groups=1000(jean),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare),129(vboxusers),1003(tester)
```

Comment: That part I understand, but what I don't understand is how come I wasn't assigned to the new group after I logged out and then logged back in.