# cannot connect to Docker daemon socket without sudo

Tags: docker

I have added myself to the docker group using command `sudo usermod -aG docker yashar`. and here is the output of `groups yashar`:

```
yashar : yashar adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

and here is the output of `ls -lah /var/run/docker.sock`:

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Apr  8 11:16 /var/run/docker.sock
```

but when I run `docker run hello-world` I get this error:

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

But running `sudo docker run hello-world` works without any problems.

Is there anything I'm missing? How can I solve this? I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I had the same issue previously although `groups yashar` is showing the correct groups `groups` may not. I had to completely reboot for it to take effect, re-logging was not enough. Unfortunately, I have no idea why that is the case and I have no answer to my question so far, so I cannot give a better answer than "reboot". https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034463/why-didnt-my-user-get-assigned-to-the-group-i-had-added-myself-to

Comment: If you have only just added yourself to the `docker` group, you would need to log out and log back in for those changes to effect your current session.  Rebooting is somewhat heavy-handed but it does accomplish the log out/log in sequence.