# Common answers to "how do I use docker CLI without sudo?" aren't working for me; what do I do?

Tags: permissions, docker

I am trying to use Docker CLI without `sudo`ing every command.

For context, I am new to Linux. I've used Linux on a DigitalOcean server for about 30 hours total. This is my first Linux laptop. It is on Ubuntu 22.04.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure the common solutions aren't working because they presume `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` will give Docker the same permissions as my logged in user. But I still have to write `sudo` before commands, so giving Docker the same permissions I have (without writing `sudo` first) doesn't change anything.

To show my research I've visited the three following pages and a dozen more I won't list that say the same thing

[cannot connect to Docker daemon socket without sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132459/cannot-connect-to-docker-daemon-socket-without-sudo)

[Allow non-root user to use some Docker commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171549/allow-non-root-user-to-use-some-docker-commands)

[How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

The summary of the advice is

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
// then one of: "newgrp docker" | "reboot" | log out and back in
docker run hello-world
```

but when I do `docker run hello-world` I get

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/rlm/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

This tells me sudo was still necessary to run docker because `sudo` before the prev cmd still works.

So what do I have to do to make these steps work for me? Do I have to elevate the account I use for my laptop (Im the only user) to root so that giving Docker my permissions removes need for `sudo`?  I don't want my typical logged in user (even if its me) to be able to run just any command without `sudo` in front of it. That seems bad to me.

Comment: "// then one of: "newgrp docker" | "reboot" | log out and back in" ... What was the output of `id` after doing one of these? Is `docker` listed as one of your groups?

Comment: the output of `id` is: `uid=1000(abc) gid=1000(pluto) groups=1000(pluto),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),1001(docker)`

`pluto` is a previous account I used before changing my username. `abc` is my current account

Comment: `1001` is unusual for Docker's gid. When you install Docker, it should set up a system group for itself with gid less than `1000`. How did you install Docker?

Comment: I used [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) I believe. @muru

Comment: There are two methods in that page, which one? Also, it says: "The docker group is created but no users are added to it" - and I took a look at the `postinst` file of  `docker-ce`, which does have a command adding the `docker` group if it doesn't exist, so I think something went wrong with your install. Best purge the packages you have installed right now and re-install it afresh.